# Entity reference view filter from node data text to exposed as check box

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type ‘protocol’, with a field ‘participants’ an entity reference view widget field which gets its view list from the users. ‘protocol’ also has a text field ‘Class’ with a single value entered.

In the user_profile I use the same text field ‘Class’, this time multiple values, comma separated.

What I would like is to expose a filter in the entity reference view that is a check box with the value from the class field data in the ‘protocol’ node.

The idea is to check a box to optionally filter the participants view for users that contain that class as specified in the protocol node. Any ideas?